# Where can I find documentation on the NMEA sentences supported by the Garmin GLO?

Tags: gps, garmin, nmea

I just picked up a Garmin GLO Bluetooth GPS device. Does anyone know where I can find documentation of the NMEA sentences it outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Does this Help?  Not sure if the sentences are device specific, and it's a bit dated.  But this could be a good place to start.

http://www8.garmin.com/support/pdf/NMEA_0183.pdf

I Found The link above in a post on the Garmin Forum [here](https://forums.garmin.com/showthread.php?71151-Garmin-GLO-programming-questions).