# NMEA sentences-PADCH,PAGCD

Tags: gps, nmea

I was looking for information on NMEA sentences.

I got to know about the terms like $GPGGA, GPHDT, GPGSV, GPGLL from GPS data. Also I could see many new terms like PASCD, PAGCD, PADCH.

What forms the source for these sentences, and what do they refer to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NMEA is the abbreviated name of the organisation. Presumably you are looking for NMEA 0183 interface specification, which you can buy from the organisation - see http://www.nmea.org/.

Garmin (and other manufacturers) have proprietary extensions (which is the meaning of "P" in the label). The Garmin ones can be found at http://www8.garmin.com/support/pdf/NMEA_0183.pdf (thanks to [Where can I find documentation on the NMEA sentences supported by the Garmin GLO?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-the-nmea-sentences-supported-by-the-garmin-glo)), but yours look like another manufacturer (since Garmin ones have "GRM"). A partial list is provided as part of the GPSD documentation at http://catb.org/gpsd/NMEA.html#_vendor_extensions.